# BackboneJS Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

I am getting this error . I am able to preform read, and remove functions using BackboneJs , but i am having error when i execute the add method any help will be appreciated.
    JSfiddel path is http://jsfiddle.net/2wjdcgky/

```
BackboneJS Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified 

$(function() {
```

Model

```
var modelContact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            Id: 0,
            Name: "",
            Address: ""
        };
    },
    idAttribute: "Id"
});
```

ModelCollection

```
var contactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: modelContact,
    url: function() {
        return 'api/Contact';
    },
    add: function(model) {
        this.sync("create", model); // Error On create
    },
    remove: function(model) {
        this.sync("delete", model); //Runs Fine
    }
});
var contacts = new contactCollection;
```

View

```
var contactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    events: {
        "click a.destroy": "clear"
    },
    template: _.template($("#newContacttemplate").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    clear: function(e) {
        contacts.remove(this.model); // runs fine
    }
});
```

Main View

```
var main = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#contactApp"), 
    events: {
        "click #btnsave": "CreateNewContact"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.Nameinput = this.$("#contactname");
        this.Addressinput = this.$("#contactaddress");

        contacts.on("add", this.AddContact, this);
        contacts.on("reset", this.AddContacts, this);
        contacts.fetch();
    },
    AddContact: function (contact) {
        console.log("AddContact");
        var view = new contactView({ model: contact });
        this.$("#tblcontact tbody").append(view.render().el);
    },
    AddContacts: function () {
        console.log("AddContacts");
        contacts.each(this.AddContact);
    },
    CreateNewContact: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        //Generate an error "BackboneJS Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified"
        contacts.add({ Name: this.Nameinput.val(), Address: this.Addressinput.val() });
    }
});
var m = new main;
```

});

Comment: You're overriding standard Backbone.Collections methods with "add", "remove", and so on, which may cause unexpected behaviour. Better give some meaning to that function names, or use directly the standard ones. If you want to save a contact and add it to the collection, call model.save() and add it to your collection in your `success` handler...

Comment: Point noted But my removes method works fine , and i have overridden it also.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSFiddle was missing Backbone references and all.

Working update: http://jsfiddle.net/apt7hchL/2/

Much simpler code (no need to define those `add` and `remove` methods on the collection!). Also more common Javascript coding style conventions.

Please note I had to manually generate an "Id" attribute to allow creating more than one contact. As you are making Id = 0 by default, second model with same is not added, as Backbone sees a model with id=0 is already in the collection.

When you want to save, call the `model.save()` method. Don't call sync manually, you'll normally don't need to!

For the model to be saved to the database before being added to the collection, use:

```
createNewContact: function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var self = this;
  var newContact = new ContactModel({                   
    Name: this.$("#name").val(),
    Address: this.$("#address").val()
  });
  newContact.save({ success: function(model){
    self.collection.add(model);
  });

  //clear form
  this.$("#name").val("");
  this.$("#address").val("");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sync method tries to sync to a server setup to handle it, with CRUD abilities.  If thats not what you're looking for, and you just want to display this information on the client side, instead of using sync, you should use Collection.add(model) and Collection.remove(model)

Comment: And your remove is working because you're not accessing your overriden remove method there, its out of scope, your referencing the regular remove I just mentioned you should use.  Again, sync method is only for interfacing with a RESTful server, its going to throw url errors if that server is not handling requests properly.

Comment: I have a server setup asp.net webapi. it is being called fine and responds to Post /Delete/PUT requests. how should i call the overridden remove or any alternative

Comment: Actually, sorry, your remove may be being called correctly, I just opened your JSFiddle and noted that you have all Javascript code together.  If you were to seperate collection and view into two seperate files, you would need a global namespace.  So which one doesn't work, add or remove, because in your description you say remove doesn't work, but in comments in code it says that add doesn't work.  And what line of code is causing the error?

Comment: updated. regarding separation of files . i can do that but as i am new to backbonejs it will be good/time saving for me to focus on the current code. But thanks for the advice.